# How do I turn on autosave for TinyMCE in Mezzanine?

Tags: django, tinymce, mezzanine

I'd like to enable autosave in my Mezzanine content authoring interface.  It sounds like there's a TinyMCE plugin called AutoSave that does this -- how do I enable it for TinyMCE through the Mezzanine setup?

Answer (score 1):

I created my own autosave plugin for TinyMCE, I can't share the code due to office rules but what you need to do is use JavaScript or jQuery and set a particular configurable interval on which an AJAX call is made to the server by sending the content of TinyMCE (using `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent`) and save it at server side.

You can also add a button for this so that before making an AJAX call just check the status of button whether it's enabled or not.

Comment: Where do you add this -- did you put a hack into the TinyMCE codebase?

Comment: It's not a hack, I didn't change TinyMCE codebase. Your HTML page where you initialize the TinyMCE editor, use it there. Do you know jQuery and how to make AJAX calls? You'll need to learn that first.

Comment: I know jQ and AJAX, but am new to Mezzanine.  Which files in the mezzanine setup should i edit?